# Retrieve more detailed errors from Electron preload script

Tags: javascript, error-handling, electron

I am trying to run a new Electron app with a simple preload script and I'm seeing a syntax error in the developer tools even though TypeScript has no problems compiling. Unfortunately as Electron only logs the error with `console.error` (which shows the error text and the line on which the error is logged in the developer tools), there is no way that I can find to view the actual location of the syntax issue. All I can see is this:
[image]

Is there any way to view the entire stack trace?

Comment: could you paste the preload script with the question?

Comment: Maybe it's too obvious, but you can access the call stack by clicking the gray triangle

Comment: @SharvinK I can get the preload script itself to run, but once I add all my imports and try and get it to do anything, it fails. Unfortunately I can't pinpoint *where* this is failing so I can't post the relevant code.

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi I wish it was that easy - Electron logs with `console.error` rather than reraising or using `console.trace`, so there is no stack trace. I updated my question with a screenshot of the expanded logs. The link in the logs is to an Electron file with a `console.error` statement, not to my code.